# Why anchors.centerIn doesn't working for Column elements?

Tags: qt, qml

I have this piece of QML code:

```
 Column {
     spacing: units.gu(2)
     anchors {
         fill: parent
         centerIn: parent
     }
     Row {
         spacing: units.gu(4)
         ...
     }
     Row {
         spacing: units.gu(4)
         ...
     }
     Row {
         spacing: units.gu(4)
         ...
     }
     Row {
         spacing: units.gu(4)
         ...
     }
 }
```

I'm trying to center Column in its parent element (a Page element), but it doesn't work.
If a try to `centerIn: parent` in one of the Rows, it works, but as I have 4 Rows, it break the layout. But Rows respond to this, instead my Column.

Why make `centerIn: parent` works for Column? Theres another ways to center this?

Comment: Hi, if you post the full file, fixing it will be a matter of minutes (in case you still  face the problem) :_)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

you can't set 'fill' and 'centerIn', 
so put column in anchors.centerIn:parent and the Rows in anchors.horizontalCenter:parent.horizontalCenter   (centerIn is not allowed cause it conflicts the parent vertical positionning....).