# Qt QML Center Center Rectangles

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick2

I want to place a set of rectangles (Flow->GridLayout->Repeater) are centered horizontally and vertically around the center of a wrapper rectangle.

When I use `centerAt: parent`, it works, but the left-most side of the grid begins drawing *from the center*, when I actually want them to draw evenly from the center:

[image: Centering Rectangles]

*Also, it would be helpful around some suggestions on how to format my QML to "scale" the rectangles [1..n] proportionally to their parent wrapper, and draw the `ComboBox` element centered in the area below the `Item:screenCaptureFramesPreviewWrapper`

Code I have now (**Updated**)

```
 /**
  *  Screen Capture Preferences Body
  */
 Rectangle {
     id: screenCapturePreferencesBody
     height: parent.height
     width: parent.width
     anchors {
         top: screenCapturePreferencesHeading.bottom
         bottomMargin: Styles.margins.small
     }
     Column {
         id: screenCapturePreviews
         anchors {
             centerIn: parent
         }
         Row {
             // Screen Frames for Preview
             Flow {
                 id: currentScreenFrames
                 spacing: 50

                GridLayout {
                     id: previewFrameGrid
                     columnSpacing: 1
                     rowSpacing: 1
                     Repeater {
                         model: CaptureService.displays
                         CFramePreview {
                             //...
                         }

                     }
                 }
             }
         }
         Row {
             // Screen Capture Selector
             // TODO Figure out how to make this center
             ComboBox {
                 currentIndex: rootDialog.screenPreviewSelectedIndex
                 id: screenCaptureSelector
                 width: screenCapturePreferencesBody.width * .25
                 model: CaptureService.displays
             }
         }
     }
 } // END Screen Capture Panel Body
```

Update:

Going off a reference from another comment I used `Column->Row` and `centerIn: parent` which got the boxes align properly at the center of the *rectangle*

*Outstanding issue still, I want to have the `ComboBox` center as well, but haven't been able to get it center properly?*
[image]
I've changed the code snippet above, which correctly reflects

Comment: Maybe the reason is the same as here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17321418/why-anchors-centerin-doesnt-working-for-column-elements

Why don't you just calculate the width of each rectangle with the parent.width and the number of elements in your model?

Comment: Do you know the size of `CFramePreview`?

What's the purpose of `screenCaptureFramesPreviewWrapper`? It has width of 0. Also, a single `GridLayout` instance inside a `Flow` does not make much sense.

Comment: @jpnumi thanks! I'll look at that, I've been able to center the `rectangles` (see updated code) using `Column->Row`, still not sure on the `ComboBox` it keeps shifting and floating over the `rectangle`

Comment: @derM thanks you reference to the question gave me some inspiration

Comment: I would love to try to help you, but I would need a complete minimal example.  For example, the code for CFramePreview is not provided (I don't think it's a QML object either).  Can you slim down your code to something that I can paste directly into QtCreator and debug directly off of that?